# Visual Studio 2013 Test Explorer - Discover Tests Failed to initialize data storage for staging test results

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I constantly get the following error when opening the test explorer in VS2013:

Failed to initialize data storage for staging test results as it threw the following exception:
'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.

In the EventViewer I see the following entry:

---

Source: SQLLocalDB 12.0
Message: Windows API call WaitForMultipleObjects returned error code: 575. Windows system error message is: {Application Error}
The application was unable to start correctly (0x%lx). Click OK to close the application.
Reported at line: 3728.

---

Does anybody have the same problem and know how to get rid of this error?

Best regards
Yannik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution that worked in my case.

1. Delete the instance folder of local db called "v11.0" (C:\Users\theUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0)
2. Start cmd window and execute the following command: sqllocaldb create "v11.0"

After this, the problems within the test explorer were solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yannik had the solution....local DB (v17) is now called MSSQLLocalDB.

**Delete "MSSQLLocalDB"**

```
(C:\Users\theUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB)
```

**Create a new one.**

```
sqllocaldb create "MSSQLLocalDB"
```